# Conformal reparametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, parametrization

We consider $$\sigma (u,v)=(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u))$$ Picking $u=\theta , v=\phi , f(\theta )=\cos \theta , g(\theta )=\sin \theta$ we get that the first fundamental form is $$d\theta^2+\cos^2 \theta d\phi^2$$

We consider the reparametrization $\tilde{\sigma}(u, v) = \sigma (\psi(u), v)$.

I want to show that the reparametrization is conformal.

I have done the following:

The first fundamental form of $\tilde{\sigma}$ is $$(\psi '(u))^2du^2+\cos^2(\psi(u))dv^2$$

So that the reparametrization is conformal it must stand $$(\psi'(u))^2=\cos^2 (\psi (u)) \Rightarrow \psi '(u)=\pm \cos (\psi (u)) \Rightarrow \frac{d\psi}{du}=\pm \cos \psi \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos\psi}d\psi=\pm du$$

We have that

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos \psi}d\psi=\ln \sqrt{\frac{1+\sin \psi}{1-\sin \psi}}+C=\ln \sqrt{\frac{(1+\sin \psi)(1-\sin \psi)}{(1-\sin \psi)^2}}+C \\ =\ln \sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2\psi}{(1-\sin \psi)^2}}+C=\ln \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\psi}{(1-\sin \psi)^2}}+C=\ln \frac{\cos\psi}{1-\sin \psi}+C$$

Therefore, we have the following: 
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos \psi}d\psi=\pm \int du \Rightarrow \ln  \frac{ |\cos\psi |}{1-\sin \psi}+C=\pm u \Rightarrow \ln  \frac{ |\cos\psi |}{1-\sin \psi}=\pm u-C\\ \Rightarrow   \frac{ |\cos\psi |}{1-\sin \psi}=\tilde{C}e^{\pm u}$$

Therefore, the smooth function $\psi$ that we are looking for is given by the relation $\frac{ |\cos\psi |}{1-\sin \psi}=\tilde{C}e^{\pm u}$, for $\cos\psi\neq 0$.

Is this correct? Could we get a specific formula for $\psi$ ?

How can we show that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is the Mercator parametrization $$\sigma (u,v)=(\text{sech } u \cos v, \text{sech } u \sin v, \tanh u)$$ ?

$$$$

---

**EDIT:**

The first fundamental form of $\tilde{\sigma}$ is $$(\psi '(u))^2du^2+\cos^2(\psi(u))dv^2$$

So that the reparametrization is conformal it must stand $$(\psi'(u))^2=\cos^2 (\psi (u)) \Rightarrow \psi '(u)=\pm \cos (\psi (u)) \Rightarrow \frac{d\psi}{du}=\pm \cos \psi \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos\psi}d\psi=\pm du$$

We have that

$$\int \frac{1}{\cos \psi}d\psi=\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1+\sin \psi}{1-\sin \psi}+C=\text{arctanh } (\sin\psi)+C$$

Therefore, we have the following: 
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos \psi}d\psi=\pm \int du \Rightarrow \text{arctanh } (\sin\psi)+C=\pm u \Rightarrow  \text{arctanh } (\sin\psi)=\pm u-C\\ \Rightarrow   \sin\psi=\tanh (\pm u-C) \Rightarrow \psi=\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C))$$

Therefore, the reparametrization is $$\tilde{\sigma}(u, v) = \sigma (\psi(u), v) \\ =(\cos (\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C)) )\cos v, \cos (\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C)) )\sin v, \sin (\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C)) )) \\ =(\cos (\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C)) )\cos v, \cos (\text{arcsin } (\tanh (\pm u-C)) )\sin v, \tanh (\pm u-C)) )\\ =(\sqrt{1-\tanh^2 (\pm u-C)}\cos v, \sqrt{1-\tanh^2 (\pm u-C)}\sin v, \tanh (\pm u-C)) )=(\text{sech } (\pm u-C)\cos v, \text{sech } (\pm u-C)\sin v, \tanh (\pm u-C)) )$$

$$$$

How do we get rid of $C$ and $\pm$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not correct. Remember that $\theta = \psi(u)$, so you need $\psi'(u) = \pm \cos(\psi(u))$.

**EDIT:** Now solve this separable differential equation.

Comment: Why does it stand that $\theta = \psi(u)$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Because in your reparametrization you're replacing $u$ with $\psi(u)$.

Comment: I edited again my initital post... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: With your editing, you've removed the meaning of $\psi(u)$. You need to use trig identities (maybe double/half angle formulas) to solve for $\psi(u)$. Eventually you'll need to remember the definitions of tanh and sech.

Comment: I edited it again... Could you take a look at it? How do we get rid of $C$ and $\pm$ ?

Comment: You pick them to get the answer you want. No one says that the Mercator parametrization is the unique answer!

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)